# Why aren't questions about software development, once closed, automatically migrated to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

In the close menu there is an option for

> off topic because > Questions about **software development** are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

Why aren't these automatically moved to Stack Overflow?

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically because Stack Overflow has [very specific rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about asking software development questions and most such questions posted on AD are written in a way which would get them closed/rejected quickly on SO if we just migrate them over. It's easier if the OP familiarizes themself with the rules, maybe searches for existing questions relating to the same topic, and then asks a specific question on SO.

Comment: Maybe turn this more into a feature request post. Where in the edit menu the OP will have the option to migrate to SO. That will give them the option to edit and move to SO when/if they feel ready

Comment: @jbis what would be the benefit of that? If they need to edit anyway they can easily create a new question on SO. If they can just migrate the post themself (which AFAIK no SE site allows) the effect would be the same as if we automatically migrate it. Maybe meta.stackexchange.com is the better place to raise this if you aim for a new feature.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I saw a post worthwhile of migration to SO. I believe that close reason shouldn't even include a link to SO — since many posts are now deleted I'm not sure SEDE could help, but anecdotally those who follow the link and post their question have it downvoted and closed anyway. People should be encouraged to familiarise themselves with the scope of the destination site, with suitable wording for close reasons, but also by avoiding automatic processes. @JBis

Comment: @grg Can you please tell what SEDE stands for? I am unable to guess the appropriate expansion.

Comment: @Nimesh [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/queries)

Comment: Thanks @grg, I wasn't aware of this tool :)

Comment: @Nimesh It's great fun, enjoy :)

Comment: Migrations also bypass things like the automatic duplicate-checking and making sure it has the appropriate tags. That (and the reasons outlined above) is why we avoid migrating questions in general. It's almost always better to simply re-ask in the question in the context of the correct site.